# Type-Casting a java object according to Android SDK Level

Tags: java, android, class, casting

I fill a list with checkBoxPreference objects programmatically. For new android SDK, there's a method setIcon() that was not implemented before.

So I extended the checkBoxPreference class and implemented the setIcon() similar to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/515681). My new class is called IconCheckBoxPreference, which has issues with Kitkat [new SDK].

I want to have something like

```
Object cbp;
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    cbp        = new checkBoxPreference(this);
    casted_cbp = CastAccordingToClass(cbp, checkBoxPreference.class); //TODO!
}else{
    cbp = new IconCheckBoxPreference(this, null);
    casted_cbp = CastAccordingToClass(cbp, IconCheckBoxPreference.class); //TODO!
}
casted_cbp.setTitle("My Title");
casted_cbp.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bla));
```

And continue my code using the variable "casted_cbp" without further SDK conditions. What could by the type of "casted_cbp"? Is there a way for doing so?
What's the best practice in such situations?

Comment: Not possible if those two don't have a common superclass that includes the methods you want to use on the casted object.

Comment: The common super class is actually the same class with two different versions: "checkBoxPreference". The older version does not have setIcon().

Comment: `...that includes the methods you want to use on the casted object`...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.

You will have to set the icon in the if, when the compiler still knows the exact concrete class.

As for the casting, use `CheckboxPreference` as the common superclass object type, so you can still call `setTitle()` independently of the platform version.

This is what the code will look like:

```
CheckBoxPreference cbp; 
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    CheckBoxPreference pref = new checkBoxPreference(this); 
    pref.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bla));
    cbp = pref;
}else{ 
    IconCheckBoxPreference pref = new IconCheckBoxPreference(this, null); 
    pref.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bla));
    cbp = pref;
}
cbp.setTitle("My Title");
```